# Size difference in apk size in closed track than shown in Play console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am uploading `.aab`(**57MB**) package to Android studio(closed track) and google play console is showing around **33.8 - 35.7 MB** as App download size. [image]

But after publishing when I am observing the size of app in closed track on play store, it showing around **78.9 MB**.
[image]

I am not sure what is happening in play store. As far as I remember, it was not the case earlier. Can somebody help me with this, as I am not releasing the app to production because of this issue.

Comment: What makes you think this is an issue? The download size and the unpacked size of the installed app are always going to be different things.

Comment: 79.8 MB is before downloading, when I am looking at the size of playstore, not after installing the app.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of where you're seeing the 79.8MB?

Comment: added screenshot